# Linux Forks Purpose?

Tags: linux, fork

in fork() , when a child process is created , usually parent waits for child to finish , so I was wondering what is the reason child process is created if it has to wait idle for it to finish anyways instead of doing the job itself? I tried reading some stuff about it but instead it for me more confused

Comment: It is a separate process you create - not just a thread. It is like starting a new program. If we were to live with just one process, we are back in the early 80'ties or on a primitive microcontroller

Comment: Start by reading on [Fork (system call)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28system_call%29) then [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are confused: The parent may "wait" for the child but does not necessarily mean it does nothing before waiting. The parent does its thing, then calls *wait*. If the child has already finished, *wait* returns immediately, otherwise the parent may be idle (i.e. not not be scheduled for execution by the Operating System) for some time, until the child is actually done.

An example: the parent in green forks the child in yellow. The child may finish before or after the parent waits for it:

[image: processes]

Some situations demand that the parent do nothing, e.g. it spawns a number of worker processes, then waits for them all to finish, thus acting simply as a manager...

Comment: wow that scheme makes it real clear, thanks for putting your time for it . So from it I take it that the fork makes it so that multi processing is allowed and the series of process are carried out in less amount of time than would of taken normally.

Comment: @Rage91 That is the idea. If you have 1 CPU the parent and the child process will just get a few milliseconds processor time alternatingly; the kernel is responsible for scheduling this (the scheduling itself takes a few microseconds itself). In machines with multiple processors, the kernel *may* (actually, *should*) run the child process on a second CPU and there is true parallelism with the work done truly in parallel, thus faster,